# Multiple Calculations VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, calculator

I'm sorry if this question has been asked so many times.
But on all the posts..i could not find a clear solution.
I asked my question before and it helped me very good...Still this problem remaining.

Make multiple calculations without pressing the '=' sign

if

```
'5+3 ='
```

then

```
'8'
```

WORKS!

But if

```
'5+5/10='
```

then

NOT WORKS

It's NOT the intention to build a difficult calcutor like (5*5)+(2+3)
It should just keep doing the calculation on the previous result

Made a sloppy solution that if the user tries to make multiple calculations
he gets an messagebox("error") and everything resets

SUB FOR THE OPERATORS

button.text becomes an operator:

```
Private Sub Operators_Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AdditionButton.Click, SubtractionButton.Click, _
                                                                           MultiplicationButton.Click, DivisionButton.Click
    Dim x As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Dim button As String = x.Text


    _Operator = button
```

if there is no value in the textbox this sub fix it

```
If ThereIsAnValue() = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Give in a value before u use an operator")



            ResultTextbox.Text = "0"
```

'if ThereIsAnValue is true it will check if there is an first number stored somewhere
    'If _IsThereAnFirstNumber is always false in the formload

Else

```
        If _IsThereAnFirstNumber = False Then
```

'the input will go in _value1

```
 _Value1 = Convert.ToDecimal(ResultTextbox.Text)
                ResultTextbox.Text = "0"
```

'now there is an value in Value1

```
                _IsThereAnFirstNumber = True
```

if _IsThereAnFirstNumber is true when we press an operator

```
ElseIf _IsThereAnFirstNumber = True Then
```

I made this garbage code...

```
                MessageBox.Show("Please press the '=' sign after every single calculation")
                MessageBox.Show("System reset")
                _IsThereAnFirstNumber = False
                _Value1 = Nothing
                _Value2 = Nothing
                ResultTextbox.Text = "0"

            End If
```

SUB FOR THE EQUAL SIGN

```
Private Sub EqualsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EqualsButton.Click
        If _IsThereAnFirstNumber = True Then

            _Value2 = Convert.ToDecimal(ResultTextbox.Text)
            ResultTextbox.Text = "0"
        End If



        Select Case _Operator
            Case "+"
                _Result = _Value1 + _Value2
            Case "-"
                _Result = _Value1 - _Value2
            Case "*"
                _Result = _Value1 * _Value2
            Case "/"
                _Result = _Value1 / _Value2

        End Select
        ResultTextbox.Text = Convert.ToString(_Result)

        _IsThereAnFirstNumber = False
    End Sub
```

So in other words, my program only enters the "garbage code" if ThereIsAnFirstNumber is true.
Cause if I press the equal sign it will become false.

But what code should I write that if get in that "garbage code" ?
To keep the calculating going on?

when I say '5+5/10=' it will go 'the garbage sub'at the '/'sign..What I want is that if press that '/' sign that the calculator stores the 5+5 and divides it by the /10 if then i would say +3 it would have to be 4 after i press the '=' sign

thanx

Comment: When you say '5+5/10=' does not work, what do you mean? You get an error? You get a result but it is not what you expected? What is the result that you expected and what is the result that you finally got?

Comment: when I say '5+5/10=' it will go 'the garbage sub'at the '/'sign..What I want is that if press that '/' sign that the calculator stores the 5+5 and divides it by the /10 if then i would say +3 it would have to be 4 after i press the '=' sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a simple calculator, your approach is not right. You should proceed as the Windows calculator works, that is, calculating the result as the operations are pressed. Its quite complicated to explain and I won't write the whole code for you, just to guide you how it can be done, you should proceed as follows;

```
 Private _result as decimal
 Private _value as decimal

 Private Sub PlusButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PlusButton.Click

  If _result <> cdec(0) then
     _result = _result + _value
  EndIf

  // Then you can add your other logics, such as writting the calculation in a Textbox
End Sub
```

You can do the same for the other signs also. 
If ever you wish to use 1 handle for all signs, then you amy use a case-else block as you did.

Comment: Thanx for your input ^^! And indeed you are right...I changed my code completely...Although I do have to say that I forgot something...You can have the operator that has been pressed at the moment the code is running...or the operator from the previous calculation...There by if there is non previous operator the value is equal to the value that has been given...if there is a previous operator...then it can be added to that same value...